# iOS AVAsset.duration is zero for HTTP live streaming but works for progressive

Tags: ios, avplayer

I have an iOS app that plays video from a HTTP Live stream "playlist.m3u8" and I have a custom player created using AVPlayer.  To handle normal user interactions such as scrubbing i need to get the duration of the video, but for some reason on iOS 4.3 using xcode 4.0 when I call the following code I get a CMTime that when converted to seconds gives a NaN -- I know what it's doing because CMTimeValue = 0 and CMTimeScale = 0 which gives the NaN and the CMTimeFlags = 17 which is even more strange.

Here's the code I uses which isn't complex at all:

```
AVPlayerItem *pItem = mPlayer.currentItem;
AVAsset* asset = pItem.asset;
CMTime d = asset.duration;
double duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
```

I should also mention that I do monitor the status of the loading playlist to make sure it's ready before i start playing/scrubbing:

```
[mPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem.status" options:0 context:VideoPlaybackViewDelegateStatusContext];
```

Thanks for any help on this issues anyone could provide.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this works in iOS 4.2 -- both simulator and device.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/AudioVideo/RN-AVFoundation-Old/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011199-CH1-SW4

The docs above mention that duration should now be obtained from the `AVPlayerItem` instance, rather than its corresponding `AVAsset`. To get the duration from the current player item via key-value observing, I use the following method (originally pulled from [`NGMoviePlayer`](https://github.com/NOUSguide/NGMoviePlayer) which was written for iOS 4.0):

```
- (void)loadPlayerWithItem:(AVPlayerItem *)playerItem {
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    ...
    // changed this from previous value currentItem.asset.duration
    [self.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem.duration"
                                     options:0
                                     context:nil];
    ...
}
```

I implemented the above change in my player and the duration is working now! This change in AVFoundation was the root cause of the issue. CMTimeFlags = 17 indicates kCMTimeFlags_Indefinite & kCMTimeFlags_Valid, and the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/AudioVideo/RN-AVFoundation-Old/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011199-CH1-SW3) specify:

> In particular, the duration reported by the URL asset for streaming-based media is typically kCMTimeIndefinite, while the duration of a corresponding AVPlayerItem may be different and may change while it plays.

Comment: Many thanks darvids0n and I feel stupid for missing the release note :-).

Comment: still returns nan for me :(, using iOS 9.0